# Query on usage of dictionary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

Below code is creating a dictionary(`foo`) and then adding a method(`bar`) and property by name `ack` in that dictionary.

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = function(){
     this.ack=3;
};
foo.bar();
```

In python, if i try doing the same,

```
>>> foo = {}
>>> def f():
    this.ack=3

>>> foo.bar = f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    foo.bar = f
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

My question:

1. Instead of (key, value) pairs, How can JavaScript allow a method(`bar`) become a member of dictionary?
2. In addition, How can JavaScript allow name `ack` with value 3(this is not key-value) become a member of dictionary?

Comment: There are apples and there are oranges :)

Comment: @thefourtheye i did not get you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of (key, value) pairs, How can JavaScript allow a method(bar) become a member of dictionary?

In JavaScript, when you say

```
var foo = {};
```

you are creating an object and when you assign something like

```
foo.bar = function(){
     this.ack=3;
};
```

it first looks for `bar` in `foo`. If it doesn't it, it creates a new attribute and stores function object in it. Here, key is `bar` and the value is the function object.

But in Python, you are doing something which is entirely different. You are using a dictionary object and when you do `foo.bar`, it looks for `bar` attribute in the dictionary object, as it doesn't find it, it errors out immediately.

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

If you are looking for a similar behaviour in Python, use objects like this

```
class TempClass(object):
    pass

foo = TempClass()
def function():
    ack = 3
foo.f = function
```

> In addition, How can JavaScript allow name ack with value 3(this is not key-value) become a member of dictionary?

Now, you are messing with the `this` object. The `this` binding happens very lately. When you invoke `ack`, it checks the object on which `ack` was invoked. Since it is on `foo` object, `this` will be set to `foo`. So, you are creating a new attribute `ack` on `foo` indirectly.

Comment: so in javascript, we are creating objects and their hierarchy(inheritance) without help of classes and in python we create objects with help of classes. Coming from java background(despite static language) how do u feel about thiS? Dont we have standard about OOP paradigm on what an object is? Does class suppose to exist before creating an object? Does access specifiers require for class members and methods? can we add dynamic attributes to an object? do u think these concepts became language specific?

Comment: @Sham Apart from the idea of everything is an object, Python's objects have to be created from classes. So classes have to created before the objects. We don't have access specifiers in Python.

Comment: but on another level javascript allows us to create  objects without help of classes. And introduced prototypical inheritance for creating hierarchy.

Comment: @Sham That is why I said you are comparing apples and oranges :)

Comment: oh ok ): i guess, apple and orange in the aspect of programming style difference for the same oop paradigm in both languages. i think, the only answer i would get if i dont like this is, write your own interpreter. But i guess there is no choice of selecting an apple or orange because javascript is the only browser language and python is not a bad choice for server side programmin

Comment: @Sham Don't forget that JavaScript can be used in server-side programming as well :)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no dictionary type. What you create whith `{}` is an Object. You can assign properties to the object like:

```
var foo = {};
foo.func1 = function () {};
foo['func2'] = function () {};
var a = 'func3';
foo[a] = function () {};
```

Comment: Don't forget the good old `(function (o) {o.baz = 'hello';}(foo));` and `(function () {this.fizz = 'world'}).call(foo);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't think of a *JavaScript* `{}` as a *dict*. It's an *Object* which is closer to *Python's* `class`.

You can add methods to instances of *Classes* like this

```
from types import MethodType as bind

class Foo():
    pass

def bar(self):
    self.ack = 3

foo = Foo()
foo.bar = bind(bar, foo) # add method bar to foo as property bar
foo.bar()
foo.ack # 3
```

---

In *Python* it's actually "easier" to set up inheritance as you don't need to `import` anything

```
Foo.baz = bar
foo.baz() # invokes inherited bar as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing dictionaries, objects, and object properties.  In javascript, `var foo = {};` is an object.   You access attributes of that object via `foo.bar;`   In python, `foo = {}` is a dictionary, not an object.  When you say `foo.bar` in python, that doesn't make any sense because a dictionary doesn't have an instance variable named `bar`.

Python can store function references inside of dictionaries though:

```
>>> foo['bar'] = lambda x: x*x
>>> foo['bar'](10);
100
```

Comment: picky-mode: "`foo = {}` is a dictionary, not an object." - `f = {}; f.__class__.__base__ <type 'object'>`

Comment: Yeah that's picky mode alright, but I accept that when most everything is an object, dictionaries are too.  Makes me wonder why primitive numbers aren't also objects.

Comment: Try `(5).__class__` ... `5.__class__` is an invalid floating-point literal.

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` in JavaScript is an object, and when you write:

```
foo.bar = function(){}; // property/method-name : value
```

It sets the `bar` method of the object `foo`, and:

```
foo.name = "Something"; // property/method-name : value
```

sets the `name` property of `foo` object to `"Something"`.

The `{}` in Python is a dictionary, and in it you do:

```
foo = {}

def f():
    foo["ack"] = 3 # key-value here

foo["bar"] = f

foo["bar"]()

print foo["ack"] # 3
```

And if you want to replicate the behaviour of dots in Python, use:

```
class Foo:  # constructor for objects
    pass

def f(self):      # `self` = object
    self.ack = 3  # object has properties

obj = Foo()  # object

obj.bar = f # object has methods

# passing object as parameter,
# or you need to do `bind` as illustrated by Paul S. in his answer
obj.bar(obj)  

print obj.ack # 3
```

Comment: gaurang is it 'def f(): this.ack = 3' ?

Comment: @Sham Oh, that was a typo. Thanks for notifying.